# View showing between another view's main Title and Content in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I will try to be as clear as i can!

1. I have created a **View block** first. Everything worked. (screenshot)

[image]

2. And then i created a **View page** second. But now there is a problem. I have the first View block between the View page's Title and Content. (screenshot)

[image]

3. And this is how it should look (screenshot)

   [image]

How do i change this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the block weight and place the block below the content in your {url}/admin/structure/block . The position of the block is determined by weight of the block at content section in the above link.

Comment: And how to do that ? i access blocks but i have no option to do that!

Comment: drag / move your block in your sites content region (created by your view) to a position below "Main page content" block.

Answer (score 0):

Change de block weight here:

/admin/structure/block

Locate and click the link "Show row weights", then you can see and order the blocks by its weight, each block will display by its weight, while the value is more negative it will display first.

Show row weights

[image: show row weights]

Block weigths

[image: block weight]